# How to deploy an operator(created by operator-sdk v1.0) without installing operator-sdk in production environment？

Tags: kubernetes, operator-sdk

With the [operator-sdk guide v1.0](https://sdk.operatorframework.io/docs/building-operators/golang/tutorial/), it is necessary to install operator-sdk in production environment when deploy an operator.

Is it possibile to deploy an operator without installing operator-sdk? Because it leads to more dependency and complexity.

How can I just generate CRD yaml, CR yaml and Contoller Image?
Or any other more convenient way to publish an Operator？

Comment: Did you try to use helm to package it from for example test environment and deploy in  production as a chart?

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I will have a try.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the make deploy command to generate deploy.yaml with all rbac and deployment objects needed for the operator.
I struggle with my self until I found this solution.

Just change the [deploy](https://github.com/operator-framework/operator-sdk/blob/74f5a36af68489d8e3d857f2fedbffacf207474e/testdata/go/memcached-operator/Makefile#L52-L54) task in the make file.

```
$(KUSTOMIZE) build config/default | kubectl apply -f -
```

To

```
$(KUSTOMIZE) build config/default > deploy.yaml
```

Then run make deploy.
And then copy the deploy.yaml and install it in your k8s or create a helm chart from it.
This worked for me no need for operator-sdk in your environment.

Edit: 
I didn't use CRD i use it to watch existing resources.
But it's look like the same solution should work with the `install` task for CRD and CR.

Answer (score 0):

The operator-sdk is not intended to directly run operators in production. Instead, you should run your operator as a Deployment inside the cluster. https://v1-0-x.sdk.operatorframework.io/docs/building-operators/golang/tutorial/#2-run-as-a-deployment-inside-the-cluster

Comment: Thx for your reply. As the describe of of the [Document](https://v1-0-x.sdk.operatorframework.io/docs/building-operators/golang/tutorial/#deploy-the-operator), we need run `make deploy` to deploy the controller. So the operator-sdk installation is necessary.

Comment: Operators scaffolded by the Operator SDK (1.0+)  include a Makefile that provides `make deploy`. https://github.com/operator-framework/operator-sdk/blob/master/testdata/go/memcached-operator/Makefile#L52-L54

Comment: Thanks for you advice, it's a way to deploy the operator, but seems like it required kustomize. Now I am using operator-sdk 0.18 to build my operator, it is more light.